# Find configuration where two cubic Bézier curves intersect at 9 points

Tags: geometry, bezier-curve

By [Bézout's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem), we know that two cubic Bézier curves can intersect at 9 points (not counting self-intersections). Is there any way to compute the end points and control points of two cubic Bézier curves that intersect at 9 points? I have a graphical description of such a configuration from the Graphic Gems IV book:

[image: Two Bézier curves intersecting at 9 points]

but I wonder if there is some way to use Mathematica or other CAS to solve this algebraically or numerically. Thanks!

Comment: The phrase "I want to _compute_ the end and control points.." doesn't look to be the right one. IMHO, it should be "Is there a necessary and sufficient condition under which 2 cubic Bezier curves have 9 intersection points ?"